# What does "Procedure NA" mean, when applied to a VOR sector?

Tags: instrument-procedures

In the RNAV-A IAP for KGAI there's a note "Procedure NA for arrival on EMI VORTAC airway radials 151 CW 269". It appears that arriving from any airway radial to EMI would have the NoPT (of the 205 outbound) apply to it, and it's not clear how to interpret this note when joining the approach at WOOLY as the IAF. So what exactly does this note mean?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

"NA" means "not authorized" here, because they don’t want you making a 163° turn from V265 NB, a 127° turn from V268 NB or a 115° turn from V3-166-457 EB over EMI. If you’re arriving from outside that arc, the NoPT routing applies.

A note like this is standard any time there is an airway crossing an IAF or feeder fix, because they don’t want you doing an uncharted course reversal over a VOR *or* anticipating the turn so early that it goes outside the protected airspace.

The note says nothing about restrictions on using WOOLY as the IAF, e.g. if you are arriving on V44-214. There’s a hold charted there, so using that as a course reversal is fine if you need one.

Comment: So if I'm arriving on V265 NB, how am I supposed to enter and perform the approach? (assuming lost comm / no radar vectors)

Comment: @GJ. In that case, file V265.YANNI.V44.WOOLY..KGAI There’s no reason to go all the way up to EMI.

Comment: Sure, Stephen, but the question is about whether, when passing WOOLY in such a way, you must or must not perform the PT.

Comment: @GJ. WOOLY is only marked NoPT if you arrive from EMI. You could ask ATC to clear you for the straight-in, but odds are they’re going to vector you to join final anyway, which is NoPT by rule.

Answer (score 0):

NA is "not authorized" here - other charts write that out.
This could be due to some restriced airspace to the south - R151 to R269 from EMI - Washington DC does have some restricted airspace in that region.

Comment: Not sure I get it. For which arrivals at WOOLY do you take it that a PT is required, and in which (other than the 205 radial from EMI) is the PT NA?

Comment: If you arrive at EMI outside the specified radials, you fly the NoPT routing to WOOLY and keep going. If you arrive at EMI on one of the specified radials, the procedure is Not Authorized. If you arrive at WOOLY from something besides the NoPT track from EMI, then you fly the holding pattern (a.k.a. Holding in lieu of a Procedure Turn) to align yourself, and then go on to the FAF.

Comment: @RalphJ what's the logic in that? E.g. if I arrive in WOOLY already on a course of 220, better aligned than from EMI, and already at the exact altitude I should be, and still have to make a full lap in the hold?

Comment: @GJ.  In a case like that, you could request ATC clearance to proceed straight in & skip the hold. There's nothing different between this approach & any other Holding-in-lieu-of procedure in that regard.